# How to efficiently generate RTTI

Tags: c++, entity, rtti, template-meta-programming, crtp

I'm trying to build an [entity system](http://entity-systems.wikidot.com/start). Each entity has a collection of components associated with it and each component is of a unique type. All components are derived from a base component class.

I need to create a class of add/remove/get Component, which takes the component type as a variable in some way (i.e. using templates). Checking the component type every time these are called using e.g. `typeid` is not efficient so I need to generate an identifier for each derived component class. In other posts here, I've seen this being done in several ways, including use of [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and use of some template function which needs to be called each time you define a derived class.

My problem with these methods (which is mostly personal) is that you have to add some kind of comment at the very least to notify whoever may be interested in creating a new Component class that he should use one of the above methods, i.e. the requirement is not explicitly visible in the code itself.

Thus, I'm looking for a method that somehow cleanly handles saving the [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) without enforcing any special rules for someone that wants to potentially use the entity system.

As an example, my best take on this is to just do a type check in the `addComponent` function. This is done using a template function which counts unique classes and returns an id for that class, i.e.

```
extern int component_id_count;
int component_id_count = 0;
template <class T>
int getComponentID(void){
    static int id = component_id_count++;
    return id;
}
```

It then checks if the id is larger than the last encountered id. If it is, a new component type is encountered and it needs to be registered. This could be quite efficient if `addComponent` is not called many times. But I still have to wonder if there's a more efficient approach to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Not sure I understand the whole problem… but you have a potential race condition in `component_id_count`. It would be better to use an additional `bool component_registered = false; if ( ! component_registered ) { register( * this ); component_registered = true; }`

Comment: Woops, the above is supposed to be `static bool component_registered = false;`

Comment: That may be true but I'm not concerned with multi-threading at the moment (I also have no multi-threading knowledge yet).

Comment: Just curious: Can you give us some number concerning the claim that "using typeid is not efficient"?

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my statement. What I meant is that the repeated use of `typeid` or other RTTI is not as efficient as other methods.

Comment: @user1294203 It's not clear what computation you're trying to eliminate. `typeid` is little more expensive than a member access — you're just getting the first element in the vtable, which is an implicit first member of the class. For a unique identifier, you can use `std::type_info const &`. C++11 adds a `hash_code` member to make it cleaner and a `type_index` convenience adaptor class.

Comment: @ Potatoswatter Yes, I know, but from some tests I ran, using the hash_code is up to 5 times slower than what I suggested in my question. The method I suggested, saves new types as they are encountered. I'm not exactly trying to eliminate a computation, but instead looking for a way that will do the same thing but no as new types are encountered but all at once.

Comment: @user1294203 You should perhaps open a new question with those tests, to verify the results.